# Importing Onsen UI to Android Studio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, onsen-ui

Good day stack developers.
I just want to ask how to import the Onsen UI into android studio
it makes me confuse how it work there because

I use bootstrap for the website however in the android studio how I can import the ONSEN